# Can I make f.checkbox optional in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have one form and checkbox inside of it

```
<%= form_for @user, user_update_path do |f| %>
  <%= Checkbox %>
  <%= f.check_box :checked, {}, true %>
<% end %>
```

The question is can I make new method inside my User controller "checked" like this:

```
def checked
    if params[:checked] == true
      true
    else 
      false
    end 
  end
```

which I will use as a param later instead of making new migration and adding checked param to User model. Now I'm getting an error "undefined method 'checked'"
I need this to set rails [settings](https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings)

Comment: You could make it a virtual attribute of `User` via `attr_accesor :checked` or you can skip the form object and just use `check_box 'user','checked', {}, true,false`

Comment: thanks for reference!